# user logouts and hadoop server shut down automatically when importing data from mysql to hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

```
bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/user_db --username asdf --password asdf --table hotels --hive-import --hive-home /opt/hive --m 1
```

Able to import data from mysql to HDFS but could not import to hive directly rather user logout occurs .
I use Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031862/running-sqoop-export-occasionally-terminates-unity-session

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--hive-table`  option