# Running `sqoop-export` occasionally terminates Unity session

Tags: ubuntu, sqoop

Bizarre as it sounds, it really happens:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1
- sqoop 1.4.6

when I run the command below on my machine which also is a single node hadoop cluster, it (occasionally) kills all hadoop process (!) and terminates the unity session.

```
sqoop-export --connect jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db_test --table \
             sqoop_quote_6faba4614c --username user --password pass --export-dir \
             hdfs://localhost:9000/inputs/id-name.csv --batch -m 1
```

When this happens, any further attempts consistently terminates the session and you have to just restart the whole machine.

I looked into kernel log and the only lines are:

```
Aug 19 13:49:02 my-vm gnome-session-binary[2165]: Entering running state
Aug 19 14:34:40 my-vm gnome-session-binary[10961]: Entering running state
Aug 19 14:36:51 my-vm gnome-session-binary[14210]: Entering running state
```

Anyone has any idea what could be the reason, or where to look to get more debug info?

Comment: Can you provide log file details, normally it will be in hadoop default directory

Comment: Sorry @KannanKandasamy for late response...I couldn't find anything other than a line in node-manager which was saying that it has received SIGTERM! (here is the last lines in log : http://pastebin.com/gmjVQ0B0)